# FastAPI async class dependencies

Tags: python, dependency-injection, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi

In FastAPI when a standard function is used as a dependency it could be used declared as regular `def` function or an asynchronous `async def` function.  FastAPI claims that it will do the right thing in either case.

However dependencies created this way are not as friendly to autocomplete as class dependencies. Also class dependencies have a bit better declaration syntax one can just specify the type of dependency once and FastAPI will figure out which dependency you mean.

def read_item(common: CommonQueryParam = Depends()):

But of the class dependency needs to execute an async operation as a part of its initialization.  Is it possible to use class dependencies and async together.  Clearly one cannot declare class `__init__` function as async.   Is there another way to make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you rightly noticed, `__init__` has to be synchronous, and you cannot straightforwardly call `await` inside it. But you can make all asynchronous code as sub-dependency and make it as input to the `__init__`. FastAPI will handle this async dependency correctly.

Sample:

```
async def async_dep():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return 1


class CommonQueryParams:
    def __init__(self, a: int = Depends(async_dep)):
        self.a = a
```